# flake8 is too strict and yapf is too low

Tags: python

I use `vscode` open my .py file. And then I see too many errors alert by `flake8` almost cross the whole file. And most of them is about whitespaces.
[image]

[image]

I use `yapf` to format the code but the code is really not changed . It seems that `flake8` is too strict and `yapf` is too simple.

Config the `yapf` to solve the whitespaces errors or config flake8 to ignore these errors? Which is the common way?

My vscode setting:

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
```

Comment: I think you need a full fledged IDE like pycharm

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to fix the issues?  I'd take a bet that your code looks nothing like what everyone else's does.  That's a problem if you ever want to share your code, or need help with it.

Comment: Maybe `autopep8` is much better than `yapf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Please edit the answer providing your code. Its not clear now if its fluke of flake8 or problem with you style
2. flake8 is usually not "too strict", its just pep8 compliance
3. Try to format your code with `yapf` manually. If you'll still have the same issue - its the problem with yapf config. If not - its problem with vscode-yapf integration. Check `yapf` config in [style section](https://github.com/google/yapf#formatting-style) and "Custom arguments to Yapf
   " in [vscode docs](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/formatting/)

Comment: Ok. There's actually violations of pep8. `flake8` is nowhere near being "too strict" in this case. Look into #3 sections - try running yapf manually to understand if the problem is in yapf conf

Comment: You are right! I use yapf in shell, the whitespaces error is all resolved. It seems there is something wrong in vscode.  After run yapf in shell, the vscode could format my code rightly too. How wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

A little too late to answer. You can try adding the `yapfArgs` flag in your VS Code settings file.

```
    "python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
        "--style",
        "{based_on_style: pep8, split_before_bitwise_operator: true}"
    ]
```

Here the `based_on_style` field can be `pep8`, `google`, `chromium` and `facebook`. You can check out the values for the fields in the `style.py` file [here](https://github.com/google/yapf/blob/master/yapf/yapflib/style.py).

With `split_before_bitwise_operator` you can override the default settings specified for `pip8` which is `false`. I wanted spaces in between the operators so I've set it. This will eliminate the E225 error you've been facing.